# How to hide a submit button in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How to hide the submit button when `$row['completion_status']=='completed'`.

My `view code` is:

```html
<input type="submit" <?=($row[ 'checklist_id']=="Denied" ||$row[ 'checklist_id']=="Approved" ||$row[ 'completion_status']=="completed" )? "disabled='true'": "";?>name="sumit_button" 
       value="Update" 
       class="btn" 
       style="float:left;background:#d8d8d8;color:#000;box-shadow:0px 0px 1x rgba(0,0,0,0.2)!important;">
```

Comment: Using with ajax ?

Comment: Seriously... you cannot put PHP into the Code Snippets box labeled as "HTML".  Code Snippets is only meant for showing us a live demo of HTML/CSS/JavaScript... nothing else.  Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this code

```
<?php 
  $display = ($row[ 'checklist_id']=="Denied" ||$row[ 'checklist_id']=="Approved" ||$row[ 'completion_status']=="completed" )? "display:none": "display:block";
?>
<input type="submit" name="sumit_button" 
   value="Update" 
   class="btn" 
   style="float:left;background:#d8d8d8;color:#000;box-shadow:0px 0px 1x rgba(0,0,0,0.2)!important;<?php echo $display; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper way to do it:

```
<script>
    $('#YOUR SUBMIT ID').submit(function(){

       //Ajax Data
       $.ajax({  
          type:'POST',  
          url:'YOUR BACKEND.php',  
          data:'YOUR DATA',
          success: function() {

              //Hide Button
              $('#YOUR SUBMIT ID').attr("disabled", true);
          },
          error: function() { 

              //YOUR Code  
          }
       });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your disable into hidden just make the output just like this

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" hidden />
```

Or make it jQuery in it since you put a tag of **javascript** in this question